# Gnuplot intensity plot with grayscale

Tags: gnuplot

I am making an intensity plot with gnuplot using the following commands.

```
set palette defined
plot 'specttest.csv' u 1:2:3  with points linetype palette
```

Is it possible to make the same plot with a grayscale palette, ranging from white to black or black to white with varying gray levels?

Answer (score 4):

Gnuplot offers many ways to specify a palette. For a gray palette, the simplest command is

```
set palette gray
```

To have the palette from white to black, use

```
set palette gray negative
```

I would recommend to use these commands, since then you can also use `gamma` to add gamma correction to the palette. With `test palette` you can see how the actual palette looks like:

```
set palette gray positive gamma 1.5
test palette
```

[image]

Other possibilities would be

```
set palette defined (0 'black', 1 'white')
```

or with `3` being the function `x` (see `show palette rgbformulae`):

```
set palette rgbformulae 3,3,3
```

or

```
set palette function gray, gray, gray
```

Comment: set palette gray is nonlinear gradient, set palette defined is linear gradient here